# Continuous delivery in bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I am new to CI/CD . I want to implement continuous integration & continuous deployment using bamboo and server as web sphere.

You could please suggest any video tutorials for it. I can see many tutorials on Jenkins but I want to implement in bamboo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the [official documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-bamboo-289277283.html).  This will help you get familiar with CI/CD terminology and ultimately help you search for tutorials on specific items that you may be struggling with.

If you prefer a video format, Atlassian has published an entire tutorial series that is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaD4FvsFdarQp-qHSr3EqWz1WLFa-HUeD).